# Amsproc conflict with natbib?

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, incompatibility, amsproc

I am getting strange compile-time errors when I try to use `natbib` with `amsproc` class -- even though the file looks fine upon compiling.  Any idea what is going on?  Is there some conflict between the `amsproc.cls` file and the `natbib` package?

A minimal example is below.

```
\documentclass{amsproc}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
\cite{doody}
\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: after testing this with all three ams document classes (`amsart`, `amsbook` and `amsproc`), i find that only `amsproc` has a problem.  it will take some time to unravel the source, as it's not obvious where the differences lie -- something is intervening at `\AtEndDocument`, and finding out what this is will require detailed code tracing.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in how `natbib` redefines `thebibliography` to set headers and the TOC entry.

```
\documentclass{amsproc}
\usepackage{natbib}

% make \bibsection to do the same as amsproc wants
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\@bibtitlestyle}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\cite{doody}

\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}

\end{document}
```

[image]